# Ignore a property while using jquery $.extend()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an efficient way to clone an object yet leave out specified properties? Ideally without rewriting the $.extend function?

```
var object = {
  "foo": "bar"
  , "bim": Array [1000]
};

// extend the object except for the bim property
var clone = $.extend({}, object, "bim");
// = { "foo":"bar" }
```

My goal is to save resources by not copying something I'm not going to use.

Comment: What about unsetting those properties afterward?

Comment: I can do that, it's just that I'd prefer not to waste the time and resources copying the property. For instance, if the value for a certain property was a large array I'd prefer not to copy it at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) takes an infinite number of arguments, so it's not possible to rewrite it to fit your requested format, without breaking functionality.

You can, however, easily remove the property after extending, using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
var object = {
    "foo": "bar"
  , "bim": "baz"
};

// extend the object except for the bim property
var clone = $.extend({}, object);
delete clone.bim;
// = { "foo":"bar" }
```

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to repress a certain property? I'm trying not to spend too much time/resources copying things I'm not going to use.

Comment: @stinkycheeseman Not without creating a new implementation. Here's the annotated source code of `jQuery.extend`, in case you're interested: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.extend

Comment: I have same requirement just because the hash contains "parent", and parent again points back to children, and it goes in infinite loop so me too wanted to avoid a key like "parent" while it performs deep copy

Comment: @AmolPujari A quick solution: First perform a swallow copy, remove the key, then perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive what you want with either [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) or [omit](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org), they both allow to make a copy of an object and filter certain keys from the source object to be included or omitted in the copy/clone:

```
var object = {
    "foo": "bar"
  , "bim": Array [1000]
};

// copy the object and omit the desired properties out
// _.omit(sorceObject, *keys) where *keys = key names separated by coma or an array of keys
var clone = _.omit(object, 'bim');
// { "foo":"bar" }
```