# How to overwrite values using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to over write values such that only existed variables are changed but not adding any additional varaible.

For example:

```
    rectangle : {
        "width" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "r" : 0,
        "stroke" : "#000000",
        "stroke-width" : 1,
        "stroke-dasharray" : "No",
        "fill-opacity" : 1.0,
        "stroke-opacity" : 1.0,
        "rotation" : 0,
        "transform" : ""
    }
```

### Need to overwirte with

```
    _newProperties = {
        "stroke" : "#FFFFFF",
        "strokewidth" : 3,
        "stroke-dasharray" : "No",
        "font-size" : 12,
        "font-weight" : "normal",
        "font-style" : "normal",
    },
```

### Result should be: (font shouldn't be appended)

```
    rectangle : {
        "width" : 0,
        "height" : 0,
        "r" : 0,
        "stroke" : "#FFFFFF",
        "stroke-width" : 3,
        "stroke-dasharray" : "No",
        "fill-opacity" : 1.0,
        "stroke-opacity" : 1.0,
        "rotation" : 0,
        "transform" : ""
    }
```

Comment: Great. Write some code.

Comment: why i am getting negative points? I can use jquery extend but it will add the new values which i don't want.

Comment: @user1595858: Your only choice would be to iterate over the properties in `_newProperties`, check each one's name for `font-`, and add it in if it doesn't start with that name.

Comment: I thought jquery has some kind of method to do it so i put this question

Comment: @Blender no, I don't think that's quite the behavior the OP wants. I think the OP is looking for something like `$.extend()` but does not want to add new properties from the second object to the first. More of an "intersection" than a "union" (though that's still imprecise).

Comment: Are those objects in separate containers ?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878983/ignore-a-property-while-using-jquery-extend

Comment: -1 Because there's no indication that you've made an attempt to solve this yourself. I have no idea what you *don't* know how to do. Seems to me that you just want someone to write this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward using the `hasOwnProperty` function:

```
for(var key in _newProperties) {
    if(rectangle.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        rectangle[key] = _newProperties[key];
    }
}
```

This loops through the keys in `_newProperties` and writes the values to `rectangle` iff `rectangle` has a property with the same name. Note that properties inherited through prototypes will be ignored because `hasOwnProperty` will return `false` for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to *update* the existing properties of `rectangle` with the properties of `_newProperties`, you'd have to use a `for...in` loop:

```
for (var prop in _newProperties) {
    if (rectangle.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        rectangle[prop] = _newProperties[prop];
    }
}
```

`rectangle.hasOwnProperty` makes sure that `rectangle` actually has that property and checks as well that it's truly `rectangle`'s property, not a property higher up in the prototype chain.